# Restoring from a Backup after Update

Tags: updates, backup

I recently updated a WP site from 3.0.1 to 3.3.1. The site has been having a lot of problems since the update. I want to restore the site to a version I backed up right before updating. I used the EZPZ OCB plugin to backup the site. Is restoring it as simple as deleting the current server files and then uploading the backup via FTP?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's never a good idea to run an old version of WordPress, so I would recommend finding the source of the issues above all else. Old versions receive no security updates and have no long-term support, so by rolling back you're leaving yourself extremely vulnerable to security issues that have since been fixed.

To fix your current install of 3.3.1, check out [Blackbox](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/blackbox-debug-bar/); it will help you find any errors. WP 3.3.1 is solid, so any issues would almost certainly be with the theme or plugins. Naturally, make sure both are up to date.

If you must roll back, first off, and I can't stress this enough, ***do a dry run on a test server*** first.

You'll want to remove all files except:

1. wp-config.php
2. wp-content/
3. .htaccess
4. Any customizations (of which there *should* be exactly zero)

Next, re-upload the old version (first removing the above from it so you don't overwrite anything). It's possible that some things in the database changed as well, so if nothing in your site has changed you could consider rolling that back too, but it's more likely than not that you won't have any trouble. Once you do this, WP will probably ask you if you want to update your database, and you should say yes. Again, do this on a test server first, and if it goes as you want, then do it live.

Comment: I'm going to work on the site offline after I restore the old version online. I uploaded the backed up files to the server in a different directory. I changed the directory that wasn't working to "millermusicllc2" and the directory of the files I uploaded to "millermusic". I then tried logging in to the site and it wouldn't let me until I upgraded WP. I refused and then I deleted wp-config.php from "millermusic" and replaced it with "millermusicllc2"'s wp-config.php file and still have the same problem. I can't find the .htaccess file in either directory.

Comment: Now I'm taking the "millermusicllc2" wp-content/ folder and I'm uploading it to "millermusicllc" after I deleted its wp-content folder.